# Adding circles with :before

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I want to add 3 green circles with the :before pseudo-element in order to show the in-stock-status of my products similar to below:

```
http://www.chililips.com/LACOSTE-Lounge-Pant-Schlafhose-lang-gruen
```

I only know how to apply ONE circle, but how can I add three or more? I also thought of using HTML characters, but there are no green circles...

Comment: we want the code you tried to see where you have your trouble. there is possibilities with a single pseudo but impossible to guess your HTML nor the css you already use.

Comment: It's quit easy and same like as you add single icon but first share your code as @GCyrillus asked

Comment: I have this:    .text:before{
   content: '';
   display: inline-block;
   width: 15px;
   height: 15px;
   -moz-border-radius: 15px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
   border-radius: 15px;
   background-color: #69b6d5;
}

Answer (score 4):

Box shadows...no pseudo-elements required. Unless you want to.

```css
.blob {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: lime;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 3em 15em;
  box-shadow: 5em 0em 0 lime, 10em 0em 0 lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="blob"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using font icons you can simply add like single one instead of three same content

```
.fa-circle:before {
    content: "\f111" "\f111" "\f111";
}
```

This is an example of fontawosome icon,you can manage space between icons by `letter-spacing`

OR

If you are using image for icon, then just take image with three icons or use multiple background images like `background: background1, background 2, ..., backgroundN;`

Read more about [multiple background images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds)